# Implement Location Listener across application

Tags: android

Hello i already have several activies that use a fake user location. What would be the fastest way to implement the real location across all my activites?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at all the tutorials / guides in the Android Guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html

Specifically the articles, lots of sample code & patterns:

- "Make your App Location Aware"
- "Deep Dive into Location"

Comment: Is there a Sample of a service that does this?